# How to build this query in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

[image]

Supposing I have this data. How to query this in such a way that will result to this in an efficient way. It will sum the qty of all OUT less the IN per item.

[image]

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Hint: Use `SUM` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: @Renzo, I tried doing it manually like ill sum the OUT first and less the IN but doint it will be inefficient I have a lots of data. select (select sum(out) - select sum(in) from table A). Something like this.

Comment: @Tim Biegelesen yes. But i just don't know how to build it like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select desc, sum(case Type when 'out' then Qty else -Qty end) from test group by desc;
```

this will be faster.

Answer (score 3):

Try this query:

```
select
    "Desc",
    sum(case when Type = 'out' then Qty else 0 end) -
    sum(case when Type = 'in'  then Qty else 0 end)
from yourTable
group by "Desc"
    Desc
```

Note that `DESC` is a reserved keyword and you should not be naming your databases, tables, or columns using it.  I think you would have to escape it in double quotes to get the query to run.

Comment: This is exactly what Im looking for. never though CASE WHEN can be used like this.

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
SELECT Description, SUM(Case WHEN rowtype = 'in' then 1 else -1 end * Qty) as rowqty FROM yourtable GROUP BY description
```

Note that it is not a good idea to use reserved words as column names.  DESC and TYPE are asking for trouble!

Comment: yes. I just used that for the purpose of this question.